# OLE ERROR 805303E in delphi?

Tags: javascript, delphi, pascal, gecko

hello
  I am testing a function to load an html code in a geckobrowser (gecko component in Delphi).
  Here the function

```
   procédure TCustomGeckoBrowser.LoadHTML (htmlCode: string);
 var
   domwindow: nsIDOMWindow;
    domdoc: nsIDOMDocument;
    domhtmldoc: nsIDOMHTMLDocument;
    nsstr: IInterfacedString;
begin
  domwindow: = GetContentWindow;
  domdoc: = GetContentDocument;
  domhtmldoc: = domdoc que nsIDOMHTMLDocument;

  nsstr: = nouvelleChaine;
  nsstr.Assign (htmlCode);
  domhtmldoc.Write (nsstr.AString);
end;
```

but the programme show an error of type "OLE ERROR 805303E8". I traced execution and found that the problem is in the line: `domhtmldoc.Write (nsstr.AString)`
  the function "write" is declared in the interface of my component:

```
    nsIDOMHTMLDocument = interface(nsIDOMDocument)
      procedure Writeln(const text: nsAString); safecall;
    .....
    end;
```

Have you encountered such an error?

Comment: What Delphi packages are you using (components) ?, I would have to replicate the error first

Comment: This seems to be an almost exact duplicate of a post on the free pascal forums: http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,7854.25/wap2.html (From 13 nov 2009 according to the printed version: http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?action=printpage;topic=7854.0 ) Have you tried the suggestion given in response to that question by "Phil"?

Comment: yes I can retrieve the html of the page or I have not found titre.mais function in c + + or Java who have the same functionality as "write"

Comment: @user653395 please use English here. And please also spell C++ without spaces.

Comment: so excuse me for my English because I'm French!!!.but what you think about my problem?

Comment: Very hard to debug, but stuff with OLE and `Interface`'s is extremely complicated. There is zero room for error.

Comment: Add the code for the function "nouvelleChaine;
"

Comment: Please simply edit your question if you wish to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I used a temporary solution that needs to create a temporary file and then load do with the gecko. but with this solution, I can not make a step backwards.

that's why I seek another solution that allows me to make change on the webpage.
 thancks for your help